# Need help in writing Regular expression

Tags: .net, regex, url-rewriting

Can someone help me in writing regular expression to match such kind of string

**Rules are:**

1. It should start with nl
2. It can or cannot have one parameter in between nl and contact (like /abc/) but not ( /abc/def/)
3. It can have anything after contact

**Examples:**

nl/abc/contact --> allowed

nl/contact  --> allowed

nl/abc/def/contact --> not allowed

nl/abc/contact/mno --> allowed

nl/abc/contactmno/ ---> not allowed

I tried writing one **("^nl(.*?)/contact(.*)$")**, but it has a problem that it allows any number of slashes between nl and contact wheras I just want at max one slash in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```regex
^nl(?:/[^/]+)?/contact(?:/[^/]+)*$
```

### Demo

This pattern says to match:

```regex
^            from the start of the path
nl           starts with "nl"
(?:/[^/]+)?  any zero or one path parameter following
/contact     /contact
(?:/[^/]+)*  followed by zero or more other path parameters
$            end of the input
```